# Facebook JavaScript SDK FB.Canvas.setSize and setAutoGrow not working in IE7/8

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, facebook-javascript-sdk

Currently I'm testing a Facebook tab page. I am using the JavaScript SDK with the recommended async init method:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : app_id,
          status     : true, 
          cookie     : true, 
          oauth      : true,
          xfbml      : true 
        });


        FB.getLoginStatus( loginStatus );
        FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow( );
        FB.Canvas.setSize( {height: 1200 });


     };

     (function(d){
         var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
         d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
     }(document));
```

I am having issues in **IE7/8** where the **setAutoGrow** and **setSize** are not responding. My tab page is **NOT** resizing to the full content at all. Instead in IE console I am getting this error whenever I call either setAutoGrow or setSize:

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support this property or method all.js, line 15 character 3916
```

I tested this in Chrome/FF/IE9 PC/MAC and all works fine, only IE7/8 are giving me these issues. Anyone know if these are known bugs with FB's JS SDK or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 520, height: 1400 });
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();
    }
</script>
```

Use this and put it right before closing body tag.

also make sure you have this markup inside the body tags also:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

Comment: -1 the setAutoResize() is depraceted/removed (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow/)